# Empty lists generate no output in the context of a while and for loops

Tags: python, list, loops, append

I wrote this little piece of code to practice loops and nested conditionals. My initial intention was to create two empty lists which would be progressively filled by appending the sorted input.
However, when I initialized the lists as `at_risk = []` and `safe = []`, nothing came out as output. What did I do wrong?
When I put an element in them (quotation marks or a string), the code runs without problem.

```py
i = 10
at_risk = []
safe = []

while i > 0:
    for kids in at_risk:
        question = input("Have you ever been questioned by the police, Y/N? or Q to end: ").upper()
        name = input("What is your name? ")
        age = int(input("How old are you?"))
        if question =="Y":
            at_risk.append(name)
            print("This young kid", name, "is at risk.")
            if age < 15:
                print("These young kids", at_risk, "are at heightened risk.")
        elif question == "N":
            safe.append(name)
            print("This kid",name," is safe.")
            print("These kids",safe,"are safe.")
        else:
            if question == "Q":
                exit(0)
```

Comment: `at_risk` is empty, so `for kids in at_risk:` iterates zero times. Then your `while i > 0:` loop will get stuck because the loop body doesn't change `i` anywhere, so it will stay 10 forever. What is the desired behaviour of your code?

Comment: It looks like your while loop is going to never end, as `i` doesn't decrease at any steps in the code. `at_risk` is empty, so the `for` loop you have running through it won't do anything. You could have an input at the beginning that asks you to put names into it, or into `safe`.

Comment: @Vulpex (nice name BTW) yes I just realized that the for loop was the issue. When an element is included, the lists are filled with the names of kids at risk and safe. And it continues until someone answers "Q", in which case it asks for name, age and exits with code 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue lies solely within these lines of code:

```
at_risk = []
safe = []

while i > 0:
    for kids in at_risk:
```

You initialize your loop with **for kids in at_risk**, however at_risk is empty, therefor it will never begin looping.  simply change at_risk and it should work!

Comment: you are correct! I didn't realize that the for loop was the reason. Obviously, there were no kids to iterate. Thank you!